# Unable to parse ISO-8601 date correctly

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm attempting to parse a date returned to me from amazons Lex chatbot API. Some example return formats are ( From the API docs https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#date )

```
“next week”: 2015-W49
“this weekend”: 2015-W48-WE
“this month”: 2015-11
```

My particular case is "2017-W47-WE".

I've tried parsing it in a couple of ways, with no luck

**Vanilla**

```
var newDate = new Date(date)   // Invalid date
```

**MomentJS**

```
moment(date)
moment(date, moment.ISO_8601).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

None of which work, Does anyone have any idea how to correctly format this date? Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe `WE` is part of [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) despite Amazon thinking that it is! You'll probably have to detect this and treat it a little differently

Comment: what does WE mean? Wednesday?

Comment: @Zanko according to Amazon it means WeekEnd, you may also have similar problems with `201X` for decade.

Comment: Presumably you want to parse it, not format it. What value should it return? A *Date* represents an instant in time with millisecond precision, it can't represent a weekend, which would require a date range or date plus duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-WE` part is abit strange. Even if you can correctly parsed it I have no idea what should be returned. Since weekend includes two days (Saturday and Sunday) so should it be an array of moment objects?

Anyway, you can get weekend alternatively like so

```
var SAT_OF_WEEK_47 = moment("2017-W47-WE".replace("WE","6"), "YYYY-[W]WW-E").format()
var SUN_OF_WEEK_47 = moment("2017-W47-WE".replace("WE","7"), "YYYY-[W]WW-E").format()
```

I explicitly declared the format and use `E`    `1..7` as   ISO day of week. Let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, different cultures have the "weekend" on different days so in the absence of a standard, what is a "weekend"?

Comment: @Zanko that looks like a cool solution, it does indeed seem to just be the "WE" which is Lex specific, so doing this on a case by case basic seems like the best solution. i'll let you know how it goes and mark this as accepted once i've tried this. Thanks